# What are the advantages of building your own Neural Network (from scratch) over a readily available one (like in sklearn)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I don't need the answer like "for good understanding of low level stuff happening in neural networks". I am already aware of that.

I want to know why build a customized neural network when there are readily available? What are the advantages. I built my own and it did not really give me better performance than sklearn one (for the classification purpose). Then why many people are doing that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calling sklearn a neural network is like calling R a statistical analysis. Are you asking what the advantage is of constructing your own neural network, or are you asking what the advantage is of writing your own software for neural networks?

Comment: I think Artiga is referring to a specific NN example in sklearn.

Comment: Are you talking about custom network *architecture* (i.e. number of layers, number of channels in each layer, activation functions for each layer, etc.) or about custom network *implementation* (i.e. write your own backprop-algorithm, write your own ADAM optimizer, etc.). I guess the answer in both cases is usually "because you think you can do a better job (compared to existing stuff)" or "because you think it's fun".

Comment: @FransRodenburg, I am not calling sklearn a NN, I know what it is. I am asking the advantage of constructing your own NN.

Comment: @Ingolifs, I am asking in general. What more values a customized NN (built from scratch) will bring on table?

Comment: @nikie custom network implementation (write your own).

Comment: Not sure this can be answered in general. Normally, you'd want the same learning performance, but e.g. lower memory usage, a simpler programming interface, faster running time, or additional features. Or maybe your code needs to run in a special environment (web browser, embedded system), and you can't find an off-the shelf implementation for that environment. Or maybe you just don't trust other people's implementation to be correct (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)

Comment: @nikie, Thank you for your response. I am not restricted to any of the stuff (like I don't have anything against what already available is!).